# Audit answers copy an existing answer? Clicking "comment" means acceptance?

Tags: bug, review-audit

I got a audit question to review today that looked strangely familiar. Checking out the question (I'd read it recently) I saw that the purported answer (just as I remembered) was word-by-word identical to one of the posted answers, just with a different poster. So I clicked on "comment" to ask about this, intending to mark the duplicate for deletion later. But I was told I had failed the test. OK; the original answer was certainly fine, my objection would have been that the "new" one duplicated the original.

Clicking "comment" when reviewing does *not* mean I reject the answer. I often comment on answers to complement what is being said, or to correct a minor point, and then accept them (or ask for deletion, as may be).

The other point is that audits by reusing questions and legitimate answers has to be handled with more care. As this case illustrates, I failed the test *because* I was doing the checking I'm supposed to do as a reviewer...